# How to center align bottom navigation bar items in iphones that have default safe area in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, flutter-ios

I found that the bottom navigation bar items are not properly center aligned in some iphones which have the default safe areas in those.For eg:In this picture the items are **not properly center aligned**. How can I canter align these items properly?

[image]

But in here the items are properly aligned.

[image].

My code is:

```
Scaffold(
          body: _children[watch(tabviewProvider).currentBottomNavIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: watch(tabviewProvider).isBottomTabbarHide ? 0.0 : (SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical)*10, //94
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,//Todo:remove
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey, //Todo:remove
               // backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7F3ED),
                selectedFontSize: 0,
                showSelectedLabels: false,
                showUnselectedLabels: false,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                key: bottomNavGlobalKey,
                onTap: onTabTapped,
                currentIndex: watch(tabviewProvider).currentBottomNavIndex,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: true,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_timeline_pink.svg',
                      lableText: 'A',
                    ),
                    label: '',
                    icon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: false,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_timeline_gray.svg',
                      lableText: 'A',
                    ),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: true,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_knowledge_pink.svg',
                      lableText: 'B',
                    ),
                    label: '',
                    icon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: false,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_knowledge_gray.svg',
                      lableText: 'B',
                    ),
                  ),

                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: true,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_offer_pink.svg',
                      lableText: 'C',
                    ),
                    label: '',
                    icon: BottmNavTabButton(
                      isActive: false,
                      imgPath: 'assets/icons/icon_offer_gray.svg',
                      lableText: 'C',
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired behavior I would set SafeArea bottom propriety to false & wrap each of your icons with a `Padding()`

```dart
SafeArea(
  bottom: false,
  child: …,
)
```

```dart
Padding(
  top: value, 
  bottom: value, 
  child : BottmNavTabButton(…),
)
```

Comment: I tried it and seems like it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: It does not remove SafeArea as you need it on iOS devices but it allows you to set some desired top padding for it to look better - if you look at facebook or Apple Store app the bottomnavbar looks like this